# Creating a website for a blogger and give admin rights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cpanel

I want to create a website (using HTML, CSS and JavaScript/Jquery) for a blogger. However, she intends to change the content and color of the page pretty frequently, without asking for my help everytime.

I know how to create Login credentials to allow a specific user to modify the page (background or innerHTML), but I do not know how to upload these changes to the server directly from the website page.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried something? Tip: have a look on how wordpress is doing it (general css and custom css that overwrites the default one.)

Comment: I actually had no idea of how to do it. I'll have a look at wordpress, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go about this would probably be to use an existing CMS (Content Management System), like Wordpress or Joomla. You will have to research the options yourself.

Even this might be overkill if all she wants is a blogging tool, it all depends on the requirements (maybe a custom theme for a bogging site would do). In any case, while it is certainly not as much fun as building something new, the existing CMS tools and blogging tools have been around for a long time and has been meeting the needs of bloggers and people who need to update websites without technical skill for a very long time.

So, my recommendation is to find a good tool, get yourself acquainted with it and learn how to customize it to fit your clients' needs, then use that.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth looking into getting a content management system like [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/) (PHP) or [Umbraco](https://umbraco.com/) (C#.net), you can code the site design then she can log in and change the content. You will have to code in functionality to change colours and whatever else she needs.